# move depedencies files of .net 5 app to subdir folder

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, runtime

I have a .net 5 wpf app with below publish settings:

[image: profile settings]

How can i set dll files to move to a folder, instead of root directory?

I used `additionalProbingPaths` but no luck.

tried this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844233/additional-probing-paths-for-net-core-3-migration), again no luck.

tried [this package](https://github.com/nulastudio/NetCoreBeauty) but need self contain which is not my option.

Comment: Why you don't want dlls to be near exe?

Comment: @Sinatr cause it bothers my customers.

Comment: [Why](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_whys) it bothers your customers? If there is no real root cause, then I can suggest [another approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/189549/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr What is difference between another approach vs using single-exe?