# .Net 6, C#, WindowsForms, Loading dlls from a sub directory using "probing" doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I know this kind of question has been asked many times already, but for older versions of .NET and on 4.8 my project has been working fine with such in app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <probing privatePath="languages;bin;"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
...
</configuration>
```

but after I update to .NET 6 - its stops, anybody knows how to make it work on .NET6?

Comment: app.config is out, runtimeconfig.json is in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844233/additional-probing-paths-for-net-core-3-migration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Additional probing paths for .NET Core 3 migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56844233/additional-probing-paths-for-net-core-3-migration)

Comment: sounds promising, will check, thanks to draw me to right direction.

Comment: Were you able to achieve Probing in .net 6?if yes kindly provide details @Gorodeckij Dimitrij